# What are the last 3 digits of $3^{100}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I find the last 3 digits of $3^{100}$. I know that the last digit will be 1. But how do I find the digits occupying the ten's and hundred's places. Please give a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The last $3$ digits essentially implies $\pmod{1000}$

$$3^{100}=(3^2)^{50}=(10-1)^{50}=(1-10)^{50}$$

$$=1-\binom{50}110+\binom{50}210^2\pmod{1000}$$

Now,
$$\binom{50}2=\frac{50\cdot49}2\equiv5\pmod{10}\implies\binom{50}210^2\equiv5\cdot10^2\pmod{1000}\equiv500$$

Answer (score 3):

Using [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function),

$\displaystyle\lambda(1000)=$lcm$(100,2)=100\implies a^{100}\equiv1\pmod{1000}$ if $(a,1000)=1$

Answer (score 0):

We can break the problem down into several steps.

Step 1: Show that the set of $\text{modulo-}200$ residue numbers,

$\quad [1],[21],[41],[61],[81],[101],[121],[141],[161],[181]$

forms a multiplicative cyclic group of order $10$ and $81^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{200}$.

Step 2: Show that $3^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{200}$ (observe that $3^4 = 81$).

Step 3: Show that the set of $\text{modulo-}1000$ residue numbers,

$\quad [1],[201],[401],[601],[801]$

forms a multiplicative cyclic group of order $5$.

Step 4: Using step 2 and step 3 show that

$\quad 3^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$