# Use Euler’s $ϕ$-function to calculate $121^{1002}$ mod $100$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> Use Euler’s $ϕ$-function to calculate
>   $121^{1002}$ mod $100$
>   without a calculator.

I know that $121^{1002} = (11^2)^{1002}$ = $11^{2004}$

Applying $ϕ$-function to $11^{2004}$, we get $ϕ$ = $11^{2004}-11^{2003}$ = $11^{2003}(11-1)$ = $10 \times 11^{2003}$

And then, how do I continue? Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, using binomial theorem:
$$121^{1002}\equiv 11^{2004}\equiv (10+1)^{2004}\equiv {2004\choose 1}\cdot 10+1\equiv 41\pmod{100}.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813379/what-are-the-last-3-digits-of-3100?rq=1  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679842/find-the-last-two-digits-of-345?rq=1   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955355/find-the-last-two-digit-of-33100?rq=1

Comment: This would be my favorite! (+1) (Although it doesn't use the $\varphi(x)$-function and the teacher had demanded this...)

Answer (score 3):

Knowing that $\phi(11^{2004}) = 10*11^{2003}$ won't help you in any way that I can see to calculate what $11^{2004} \pmod {100}$ is.

But Are you familiar with Euler's Theorem that states if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ then $a^{\phi n}\equiv \pmod {n}$?

So as $\phi(100) =40$ and $\gcd(11,100) = 1$, Euler's Theorem allows us to conclude:

$11^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod {100}$.

Can you take it from there?

> $11^{2004} \equiv 11^{40*50 + 4}\pmod {100}$.  Can you take it from there?

.

> $11^{40*50+4} = (11^{40})^{50}*11^4\equiv 1^{50}*11^4 \pmod {100}$.  Can you take it from there?

.

> $11^4 = 121^2 = (100 + 21)^2$

Comment: And how do I continue from your last step?

Comment: Are you asking me what $21^2 \pmod {100}$ is?

Comment: yes cause I need to get it without a calculator as the prof said no calculators

Comment: You need a calculator to figure out what the last two digits of $21^2$ are???  ......  Okay.  The pencil and paper method is $21^2 = 21\times 21= 21\times (20 + 1)$.  In one row you write "$21$" as the result of $21\cdot 1$ from the "ones" value. And in the next row you write "$42-$" as the result of $2\cdot 21$ from the "tens" value.  You add up to "ones" column and get $1+-=1$ in the "ones" column.  You add up the $2+2=4$ in the "tens" column. And then you add up $-+4 = 4$ in the "hundreds" column.  The result is $441$ and the last two digits are $41$.

Comment: But a better method is $21^2 = (2*10 + 1)^2 = 2^2*100 + 2*2*10 + 1\equiv 2*2*10 + 1\pmod{100}$....  I'm pretty sure your professor is assuming $11^4\pmod {100}$ was not meant to be an issue.  You could to $11^4 = (10 + 1)^4 = 10^4 + C_{4,3}10^3 + C_{4,2}10^2 + 4*10  + 1 \equiv 4*10 + 1\pmod{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You're confusing the number to be exponentiated and the modulus.

We need $\varphi(100)==\varphi(2^2)\varphi(5^2)=40$, so
$$ 121^{1002}=11^{2004}\equiv 11^{2004\bmod40}\mod 100. $$

Comment: I didnt understand this : $11^{2004}\equiv 11^{2004\bmod40}$

Comment: Since $x^{40}\equiv 1\mod 100$ for all $x$ coprime to $100$… Is it clear?

Comment: If $a^k \equiv c\pmod n$ then $a^{m*k + j} \equiv (a^k)^m*a^j \equiv c^m*a^j \pmod n$.  And if $c=1$ and $a^k\equiv 1$ then $a^{m*k +j}=(a^k)^m*a^j\equiv 1^m*a^j \equiv a^j \pmod n$.

Comment: And $2004 = m*40 + j$ for *some* integer $m$ and some integer $j; 0 \le j < 40$.

Comment: and so $121^{1002}$ mod $100$ $\equiv$ $11^{2004}$$^{mod 40}$ mod $100$?

Comment: Yes : $\;\equiv 11^4\equiv 21^2=400+41\equiv 41\mod 100$.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's theorem (a generalization of Fermat's little theorem), if $m\geq 1$ and $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then

$$a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod{m}$$

So

$$121^{40}\equiv 1 \mod{100}$$
and raising both sides to the power of 25, we have
$$121^{1000} \equiv 1 \mod{100}$$
You should be able to finish from here.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the $\phi-$function is not really required because the cycle of powers of $21$ is very short.

Indeed $21^r\equiv 01,21,41,61,81\pmod{100}$ for $r=0,1,2,3,4$

So $121^{1002}\equiv 21^{1002}\equiv 21^{(1002 \mod 5)}\equiv 21^2\equiv 41\pmod{100}$

Comment: "because the cycle of powers of 21 is very short."  Your definition of "very" differs from mine and your willingness to determine the exact length when you initially have no idea how long or short it is is ... admirable.  But $\phi(100)= 40$ is exceedingly easy, and noting $2004 \equiv 4 \pmod {40}$ and calculating $11^4\pmod {100}$ are all together a *lot* less work than calculating the first five cycles of $21^r$ and one has the advantage of knowing the process will end in success before one begins.

Comment: ?? what did I do to deserve so much hate ?

Comment: Where do you see any hate?

Comment: Interesting approach @zwim !